# Add class only on mobile - Vuejs and bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I want to add a class only on mobile. I have done this before using vuetify however it seems more difficult with vue:

**code:**

```
<div class="{'mobileSnackBar': breakpoint.xs}">
  <p> This is my snackbar </p>
</div>
```

in vuetify you have the `$vuetify.breakpoint.xs` however how would i get a similar effect with bootstrap? Or please recommend an alternative.

Comment: Why are you not using a CSS mediaquery?

Comment: Well because with vuetify, this method was much cleaner. Hence I am looking for a similar alternative

Comment: Misusing JS for what is naturally CSS' job is never "much cleaner". The opposite is true.

Comment: Do you have an attempted Vue snippet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With vuetify you can do:

```
computed: {
    is_screen_small() {
        return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.smOnly
    },
}
```

And combine it like this:

```
<div class="{'mobileSnackBar': is_screen_small}">
  <p> This is my snackbar </p>
</div>
```

Please make sure you read vuetify docs for [breakpoints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/breakpoints#breakpoint-object) to know more.

However as I know with bootstrap the only way is to use media queries:

```
// Small devices 
@media (max-width: 760px) { 
  //Add your style here
 }
```

Though, there is a solution which is not related to bootstrap:

```
computed: {
  is_mobile() {
    const isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)")
    return isMobile.matches ? true : false
  }
}
```

And combine it like :

```
<div class="{'mobileSnackBar': is_mobile}">
  <p> This is my snackbar </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately going by the size of the screen is no guaratee that your using a mobile device with touch.  If you shrink your desktop screen enough, it will think its mobile.  So  you need to be a bit careful, especially if you need to trap mouse events such as mouseover or mouseleave.  Further more some pc's have touch screens these days so both mouse and touch events can be triggered... Its a bit of mine field.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with bootstrap is to use the breakpoint classes to show/hide elements, something like this:

```
<div class="mobileSnackBar d-sm-none">
   <p> This is my snackbar </p>
</div>
<div class="d-none d-sm-block">
   <p> This is my snackbar </p>
</div>
```

Makes more sense with components rather than html, and maybe even then not the cleanest solution, but it does work.